# ElasticSearch nested aggregation query for date period: I want to know for a period of time how many users were in each "weight" per day (end of day)

Tags: elasticsearch

Given a time range: `2019-10-10`-`2019-16-10`,

I want to get the amount of users active in each day grouped by their `weight`

Data set example:

```
{
    "user": "Tom",
    "start_date_time": "2019-10-10 10:00:00",
    "end_date_time": "2019-10-10 11:00:00",
    "weight": 5,
    .....
}

{
    "user": "Tom",
    "start_date_time": "2019-10-10 11:00:00",
    "end_date_time": "2019-12-10 11:00:00",
    "weight": 10,
    .....
}

{
    "user": "Tom",
    "start_date_time": "2019-12-10 11:00:00",
    "end_date_time": "2019-14-10 11:00:00",
    "weight": 15,
    .....
}

{
    "user": "Tom",
    "start_date_time": "2019-14-10 11:00:00",
    "end_date_time": ,
    "weight": 20,
    .....
}
{
    "user": "Seva",
    "start_date_time": "2019-12-10 08:00:00",
    "end_date_time": "2019-13-10 09:00:00",
    "weight": 5,
    .....
}

{
    "user": "Seva",
    "start_date_time": "2019-13-10 09:00:00",
    "end_date_time": "2019-15-10 11:00:00",
    "weight": 15,
    .....
}

{
    "user": "Seva",
    "start_date_time": "2019-15-10 11:00:00",
    "end_date_time": null",
    "weight": 20,
    .....
}
```

Expected result:

```
Date        Weight Unique Count
2019-10-10  5       1
            10      1
            15      0
            20      0
2019-11-10  5       1
            10      1
            15      0
            20      0
2019-12-10  5       1
            10      0
            15      1
            20      0
2019-13-10  5       0
            10      0
            15      2
            20      0
2019-14-10  5       0
            10      0
            15      1
            20      1
2019-15-10  5       0
            10      0
            15      0
            20      2
2019-16-10  5       0
            10      0
            15      0
            20      2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "days": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "end_date_time",
        "interval": "day",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "weights": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "weight"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "user_count": {
              "cardinality": {
                "field": "user.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it is not exactly answered on my question because it doesn’t take the last value of the weight for the user

Comment: Can you be more precise?

Comment: It just makes the aggregation on a daily resolution but it won’t filter the rows inside that day, as a result, if we will have more than one records per day it is not taken in the decision (the user will be counted in any of the weights he has during that day)